# Exception: cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java

i am getting an exception and i don't how to fix .

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xitee.ccpt.entity.ProjectRoleSkill cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

at com.xitee.ccpt.ui.project.ProjectRoleSkillGrid$3.buttonClick(ProjectRoleSkillGrid.java:222) ~[classes/:na]

```
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    Long projectRoleSkillId = (Long) getValues().iterator().next();
    ProjectRoleSkillAddWindow projectRoleAddWindow = new ProjectRoleSkillAddWindow("Add Project Role Skill",
    new DialogWindowListener<ProjectRoleSkill>() {
        @Override
        public void dialogConfirmed(ProjectRoleSkill projectRoleSkillUpdated) {
            projectRoleSkillUpdated.setProjectRole(projectRole);
            projectRoleSkillUpdated.setProjectRoleSkillId(projectRoleSkillId);
            projectRoleSkillService.save(projectRoleSkillUpdated);
            refreshContent();
        }

        @Override
        public void dialogClosed(boolean confirmed) { }
    });
    rojectRoleAddWindow.loadToEdit(projectRoleSkillService.findProjectRoleSkillByIdForEditWindow(projectRoleSkillId));
    CcptUI.getCurrent().addWindow(projectRoleAddWindow);
}
```

Comment: You're trying to convert a `ProjectRoleSkill` to a `Long`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Long projectRoleSkillId = (Long) getValues().iterator().next();
```

This is not a Long. I assume `getValues()` returns an iterable of type `ProjectRoleSkill`.

To avoid this, instead of having

```
public Set<Object> getValues() {
    return new HashSet<Object>(grid.getSelectedRows());
}
```

you should rewrite the method signature to

```
public Set<ProjectRoleSkill> getValues() {
    return new HashSet<>(grid.getSelectedRows());
}
```

This way, the IDE won't let you cast to Long. You'll also then be able to see the `getId()` method I assume is on the `ProjectRoleSkill` class.

Comment: Plus, the ProjectRoleSkill object returned probably has an internal ID which is a Long which can be obtained by calling getId() on it which OP forgot to write.  Presumably.

Comment: @BenR Can you give me more details please ?

Comment: @IliaTapia I'm not really sure how much more detail I can give, this is a fairly fundamental concept in Java.

Comment: i am junior in java so i dont know what you mean in fact >so you said rewrite the method signature to public Set<ProjectRoleSkill> getValues() { what about the odher part , and yeah i have one getProjectRoleSkillId , but i dont understand your idea to be honest @BenR.

Comment: If you're using Java 1.6 or higher, you can replace `<Object>` in the return statement with `<>`. The rest of your program needs to know that `getValues()` doesn't just return `Object`s, it returns `ProjectRollSkill`s. Otherwise, the rest of your program can't call `getProjectRoleSkillId`.

Comment: I'm referring to the version of the Java language you're using to develop. It's not related to the version of Vaadin.

Comment: ...... Can you explain in what way it does not work, please? "It does not work" provides no information with which I can help.